# "Lassen" plus modal verb plus double infinitive

Tags: word-order, verbal-complex

Why is it correct to say:

> Ich habe das machen lassen müssen.

Why is it not correct to say:

> Ich habe das müssen machen lassen.

Answer (score 2):

This is just how infinitives work in German.

- Ich habe müssen. / Was hast du müssen?
- Ich habe lassen müssen. / Was hast du lassen müssen?
- Ich habe das machen lassen müssen.

The "main" infinitive comes last, the verbs that further clarify its meaning come before it.

This is completely analogous to how everything else works: Anywhere that you have an infinitive, the infinitive comes last, then everything that further clarifies the meaning of the infinitive comes before it. For example: *Ich muss morgen früh aufstehen.* This principle doesn't change just because there are more infinitives.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and easy rule you can follow. The order of verbs is exactly the opposite than in English. Let's look at a dependent clause first, because it's the regular one in German.

> Du weißt, dass ich heute das Feuerwerk **funkeln sehen gehen will**.

> You know that I **want to go watch** the fireworks **sparkle** today.

In the main clause, the V2 rule adds another complication. The finite verb is moved from the very end to second position. All other verbs stay where they are.

> Ich **will** heute das Feuerwerk **funkeln sehen gehen**.

> I **want to go watch** the fireworks **sparkle** today.

This works as well for your example. It's a bit more complicated though because *machen lassen* collapes into a past participle in English, as English prefers passive voice in this kind of expression. Also, *müssen* translates into *to have to* in this context.

> Ich **habe** das **machen lassen müssen.**

> I had to have it made.

And, for completeness, the Perfekt of modals adds another complication, this time in German. The combination of the auxiliary *haben* and the modal *Ersatzinfinitiv* calls for a different position of the auxiliary in dependent clauses.

> Du weißt, dass ich das **habe machen lassen müssen.**

Do you see it? *Habe* goes in front of the infinitives row instead of the very end, where it would go with normal Perfekt with a Partizip II. The order of infinitives does not change.